# Saving Audio file in AngularFire Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, firebase, angularfire

I am working on an application which deals with audio files. User needs to upload an audio file which can be assigned to user's settings etc.

I am working on Services oriented architecture.
Front-end is in AngularJS with Angular Fire
Backend is Firebase while data stored in firebase is to be used by an API written in node for different kind of manipulations and store them back in firebase or to do some extra actions and expose them to a third party application on data edited by user through angularFire application.

Now the scenario I am facing is,
I need to upload an Audio file through angular fire application which is hosted on Firebase hosting and is using firebase as backend and make that audio file accessible to both NodeJS API and my Angular Fire application.

NodeJS API is hosted on Google App Engine's Managed VM.
its preferred it solution is using some google cloud technology instead of Amazon S3 to store file.

Still open to suggestion. Don't know how can I do this.

Comment: How big can the audio files be?

Comment: It would be a 30 to 40 seconds welcome message. I think we can limit it to somewhere around 2 or 4 mb